# get the timespent from datetime from current row to the next row mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I would like to compute and display the time spent between the datetime column from current row to the next row.

current table:

```
task_id | task    | date                | user_id
      1 | Task 1  | 2017-04-30 08:30:23 | 35
      2 | Task 2  | 2017-04-30 09:30:23 | 35
      3 | Task 3  | 2017-04-30 10:00:23 | 35
```

expected results:

```
task_id | task    | date                | timespent
      1 | Task 1  | 2017-04-30 08:30:23 | 60
      2 | Task 2  | 2017-04-30 09:30:23 | 30
      3 | Task 3  | 2017-04-30 10:00:23 | (compute it by current time)
```

I have a query like this but it seems it cannot get my expected results

```
SELECT A.task_id, A.date,A.task,A.user_id, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.date,B.date) AS timespent
FROM tbl_task A CROSS JOIN tbl_task B
WHERE B.task_id IN (SELECT MIN(C.task_id) 
FROM tbl_task C 
WHERE C.task_id > A.task_id) 
AND A.user_id = 35
AND Month(A.date) = 5
ORDER BY A.task_id ASC
```

The issue of above query is it cannot get the last row or if the row is just one record. I would like to compute the last record or single record timespent by the current time now();
Any idea? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please show the schema of the source table, with the sample data to produce your sample output.

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN to keep the last row.

Comment: @SloanThrasher add the current schema and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the last row you should use a LEFT JOIN. The condition for the `B.task_id` should be in the ON clause. And you can use `COALESCE(B.date, NOW())` to replace NULL with the current timestamp.

```
SELECT A.task_id, A.date,A.task,A.user_id, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.date, COALESCE(B.date, NOW())) AS timespent
FROM tbl_task A
LEFT JOIN tbl_task B ON B.task_id = (
    SELECT MIN(C.task_id) 
    FROM tbl_task C 
    WHERE C.user_id = A.user_id
      AND C.task_id > A.task_id) 
WHERE A.user_id = 35
  AND Month(A.date) = 5
ORDER BY A.task_id ASC
```

Note that I also added `C.user_id = A.user_id` to the WHERE clause of the subquery. Otherwise you might get a `task_id` of another user.

Since you only need the `date` from the next row, you can avoid the subquery using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT A.*, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.date, COALESCE(MIN(B.date), NOW())) AS timespent
FROM tbl_task A
LEFT JOIN tbl_task B
    ON  B.user_id = A.user_id
    AND B.task_id > A.task_id
WHERE A.user_id = 35
  AND Month(A.date) = 5
GROUP BY A.task_id
ORDER BY A.task_id ASC;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/SDWX89625

Answer (score 1):

Use an outer join. And if `B.date` is NULL, use `NOW()` instead.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT A.task_id
      , A.date
      , A.task
      , A.user_id
      , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.date,IFNULL(B.date,NOW()) AS timespent
 --                                 ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^           
   FROM tbl_task A 
   LEFT
-- ^^^^
   JOIN tbl_task B
     ON B.task_id IN 
--   ^^   
                     ( SELECT MIN(C.task_id) 
                         FROM tbl_task C 
                        WHERE C.task_id > A.task_id
                     ) 
    AND A.user_id = 35
    AND MONTH(A.date) = 5
  ORDER BY A.task_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    a.task_id, 
    a.date,
    a.task,
    a.user_id, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,a.date,IF(b.date IS NULL,CURRDATE(),b.date) AS timespent
FROM tbl_task a
LEFT JOIN tbl_task b
ON a.task_id > b.task_id
WHERE a.user_id = 35
AND month(a.date) = 5
GROUP BY a.task_id
ORDER BY a.task_id
```

Basically, by using a left join, records without a match will have null values for their columns. The timespent column tests for a null, and uses the curr_date() instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply. got error /* SQL Error (1305): FUNCTION mydb.ID does not exist

Comment: Oops! Corrected a typo, please try again. (_IF_ was _ID_)

Comment: CURR_DATE() does not exist

Comment: Sorry about that. Changed to CURRDATE()

Comment: it looks it duplicates the results :) btw thanks for the effort